# Default Assignment Operator is Good For Vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, deep-copy, assignment-operator

If a class has a pointer, we must make a deep copy by overloading the assignment operator (a shallow copy wouldn't be correct).

So, is it necessary to make a deep copy (by overloading `operator=`) if a class has a member vector?

Comment: A note on terminology: you don't *overload* the assignment operator. Overloading has another meaning. What you do here is defining your own version of the assignment operator, instead of relying on the default one which is generated automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> If a class has a pointer we must do deep copy with assigment operator
>   overloading(not shallow copy).

Only if that pointer is a so-called "owning" pointer, i.e. if the class semantically owns the resource pointed at and is responsible for its eventual release or destruction.

A pointer may also be a so-called "observing" pointer which points to something which another part of the code is responsible for. An observing pointer is similar to a reference.

Keep this in mind before you blindly implement deep copies everywhere.

> So is it necessary do deep copy(operator= overloading) if a class has
>   a member vector? ?

Only if it's actually a pointer to a vector *and* if that pointer is an owning pointer.

This should practically never be the case.

I assume you are really talking about a normal non-pointer member variable anyway:

```
class Example
{
// ...
    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

In this case, you don't have to deal with pointers at all. `std::vector` manages everything automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` can take care of itself. You don't need to do anything special with it. It has its own assignment operator that does the appropriate copying.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Is it valid for array too ?

Comment: @tarktark - it helps to [read the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (look for `operator=`)